# Como asigno un nombre personalizado al objeto __proto__ que se visualice en la consola?

Tags: javascript

estoy creando un array con un prototype personalizado y queria cambiar el nombre de objeto de forma que se visualice cuando lo muestre en la consola, hasta ahora lo e logrado con este codigo:

```js
class MYarray extends Array {

 get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
     return 'MYarray';
  } 
}
 let elements = new MYarray; 
  elements.push('foo');
 console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(elements));
```

ahora aunque no me afecta en nada quería saber si había posibilidad de cambiar el nombre que aparece al lado del objeto **proto** para que se muestre con el nombre personalizado, actualmente se visualiza así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera mostrar MYarray en vez de Array. Agradezco su orientación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución Resulta que se asigna según el nombre de la clase de la que se extiende el objeto, por eso no todos los **proto** muestran un nombre, por que algunos no heredan propiedades. Para lograr lo que quiero solo es necesario crear una clase adicional que se extienda a Array:

```
class list extends Array{
    
}

class MYarray extends list {

    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
        return 'MYarray';
    }   
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si esto sirva, muy interesante tu pregunta, pero si sirve igual sería un poco raro:

```
 MYarray.__proto__ = "MYarray";
```

Comment: Esto cambiaría completamente el valor del objeto __proto__ al string "MYarray".

Comment: Eso era lo que me temia... Ummmm no tengo idea realmente pero sería muy interesante lograr algo así.